# Parsing stored procedures in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, procedure

I have been asked to find the impact of amending a field name on a table and subsequently finding the impact of this change.

Whilst it's quite easy to identify the tables affected, I am having an issue in trying to identify affected store procedures.

I am also hoping that this script will also aid in development; being able to identify all necessary procedures.

I have some code below that creates a temp table with a procedure name and a field that will contain the procedure's text (sp_helptext).
My plan (although not elegant) can get procedure name, paramaters and procedure text if I can get the contents of sp_helptext into the field.

```
--drop procedure dbo.sp_getProcText
create procedure dbo.sp_getProcText
(
      @proc_name varchar(max),
      @output varchar(max) output
)  

AS  
    BEGIN  
        declare @exec_string varchar(max);
        set @exec_string = 'sp_helptext' + ' ' +  @proc_name 
        exec sp_executesql @exec_string, @output
    END
go

create table #temp_sp_parse( proc_name varchar(max), proc_text varchar(max));
go

declare @proc_text_out varchar(max)

insert into 
    #temp_sp_parse (proc_name, proc_text)
        select 
            sysobjects.name , exec dbo.sp_getProcText(sysobjects.name, @proc_text_out) 
        from 
            dbo.sysobjects 
        join 
            dbo.syscolumns  on 
                syscolumns.id = sysobjects.id 
        where 
        (
            syscolumns.name like N'%rti%' and
            sysobjects.name like '%%'
        )
        and 
            sysobjects.type ='P'
go

select * from #temp_sp_parse
drop procedure sp_getProcText
drop table #temp_sp_parse
```

MS SQL has an issue with the exec within the insert.

Can anyone recommend a fix or possibly a better solution.

Comment: My advice is to change the name of the stored procedure and not use the **sp_** prefix [as Microsoft recommends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (Product specific code there...)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a blog post about this:
http://anehir.blogspot.com.tr/2012/11/ms-sql-search-within-programmable.html

Basically you use a system view: sys.syscomments.
Full code is below:

```
declare @keyword1 varchar(50) = 'SomeTable'
declare @keyword2 varchar(50) = 'SomeColumn'

create table #t
(
 [ReferencingDatabase] varchar(100),
 [ReferencingSchema] varchar(100),
 [ReferencingObject] varchar(100),
 [ReferencingObjectType] varchar(100),
 [HelpText] varchar(300)
)

declare @cmd1 varchar(8000)
set @cmd1 = '
use ?
if ''?'' not in (''distribution'', ''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'', ''mssqlsystemresource'')
begin
 insert into #t
 select
  ''?'' as [ReferencingDatabase],
  s.name as [ReferencingSchema],
  o.name as [ReferencingObject],
  o.type_desc as [ReferencingObjectType],
  ''sp_helptext '''''' + s.Name + ''.'' + o.name + '''''''' as [Script]
 from sys.syscomments c
 left outer join sys.objects o on o.object_id = c.id
 left outer join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
 where
 c.text like ''%' + @keyword1 + '%''
 and c.text like ''%' + @keyword2 + '%''
end
'
exec sp_msforeachdb @cmd1
select * from #t
drop table #t
```

Comment: Excellent. You would think that something like this would be a built into the server.

Comment: Actually there is also this view: sys.sql_expression_dependencies which lists dependencies found while parsing programmable objects. But I've encountered missing dependencies with this vew. My theory is that some dependencies are lost while dropping/adding columns to tables.